# How to enable Stata kernel in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, stata

I am using MacOS and try to use Stata in the jupyter notebook. I went over the following step to do so.

First, in the terminal:

```
pip install stata_kernel
python -m stata_kernel.install
conda install -c conda-forge nodejs -y
jupyter labextension install jupyterlab-stata-highlight

pip install ipystata
```

And then in my jupyter notebook:

```
import ipystata 
from ipystata.config import config_stata  
config_stata('/Macintosh HD⁩/Applications/Stata/StataSE')
```

```
import ipystata
%%stata 
display "Hello, I am printed in Stata."
```

But I keep getting the error message

**UsageError: Line magic function `%%stata` not found.**

I am not sure if this is path problem or something else.
Could you help me to fix the problem?

Comment: I don't know why you are trying to type anything in your jupyter notebook, normally you can switch between kernels in the 'Kernel' menu, then 'Change kernel' and select Stata. If the Stata kernel is loaded, you should see Stata's logo instead of Python's in the top right corner.

Comment: @krasnapolsky, I want to run stata along with python, thinking maybe it is more convenient without changing kernel. My understanding is under stata kernel I can't run python code. That is all.

Comment: I don't know then, but if that can help Stata 16 provides python integration: https://www.stata.com/new-in-stata/python-integration/

Comment: thanks, I just want to use python as my major environment and stata as supplementary.   hope to fix this soon.